# What is wrong with my solution?(hackerrank exercise - bitwise operation)

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

[the link for the excersize](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-bitwise/problem?isFullScreen=true)
In short, ‘n’ is series of number from 1 to n, and ‘k’ is a number.
I need to return the largest result of a&b (a<b) as long as it’s smaller than k, for example 1&2, 1&3 …2&3,2&4…

I get 0 whenever I run this function:

```js
function getMaxLessThanK(n, k) {
  let maxPV = 0;
  for (let a = 1; a < n; a++) {
    for (let b = a + 1; b <= n; b++) {
      if (a & b < k && a & b > maxPV) {
        maxPV = (a & b)
      }
    }
  }
  return maxPV
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) problem.

Comparison operators (`<`, `>`, ...) have higher precedence than bitwise AND (`&`), so you need to use parentheses to group:

```
if ((a & b) < k && (a & b) > maxPV) {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
function getMaxLessThanK(n, k) {
  let maxPV = 0;
  for (let a = 1; a < n; a++) {
    for (let b = a + 1; b <= n; b++) {
      if ((a & b) < k && (a & b) > maxPV) {
        maxPV = (a & b);
      }
    }
  }
  return maxPV;
}

console.log(getMaxLessThanK(8, 5));
```